# Duplicate item in todolists in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple todo-list using js. I am trying to store the value of the input in the localstorage and while i am trying to render the lists dynamically, it gets duplicate list item.

Here's my code:
`

```
    const user_name = document.getElementById("username");
const submit = document.getElementById("submit");
const ul_lists = document.getElementById("ul-lists");

let items = [];

console.log("localstorage", localStorage);
function submit_value() {
  event.preventDefault();
  items.push(user_name.value);
  local_storage = localStorage.setItem("lists", JSON.stringify(items));
  user_name.value = "";
  console.log("localstorage", localStorage);

  render_elements();
}

function render_elements() {
  let stored_item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lists"));
  console.log(stored_item);
  for (let i = 0; i < stored_item.length; i++) {
    const Li = document.createElement("li");
    Li.textContent = stored_item[i];
    ul_lists.appendChild(Li);
  }
}
```

`

Comment: Is `items` containing duplicate values?

Comment: using `event.preventDefault();` without receiving `event` parameter. That's interesting but incorrect.

Comment: @decpk Only if your browser doesn't support [`window.event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event#browser_compatibility) anymore.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that shows the actual behavior.

Comment: @Andreas Isn't that Deprecated and not recommended to use.

Comment: Deprecated !== not supported. Yes, you shouldn't be using it, but it still works... :/

Comment: That's not true. It is not supported in Firefox (2 - 65) You should see [can I use window.event](https://caniuse.com/?search=window.event)

Answer (score 1):

The reason your items get duplicated on every new input is because you are calling the `render_elements` function inside the `submit_value`.
You should extract the code to create an element in a new function and use it inside `render_elements`and `submit_value`.

```js
function createNewItem(text){
    const Li = document.createElement("li");
    Li.textContent = value;
    ul_lists.appendChild(Li);
}
```

Change your `submit_value` function like:

```js
function submit_value() {
  items.push(user_name.value);
  localStorage.setItem("lists", JSON.stringify(items));
  createNewItem(user_name.value);
  user_name.value = "";
}
```

and change `render_elements` function like:

```js
function render_elements() {
  let stored_item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lists"));
  for (let i = 0; i < stored_item.length; i++) {
     createNewItem(stored_item[i]);
  }
}
```